# C# mouse_event click doesn't work in my case

Tags: c#, click, mouse

I'm using a c# code to click on other process window,It's work great but it doesn't work when i want to click in Bluestack(Android Emulator) window.
any idea ?

the code :

```
[DllImport("user32.dll",CharSet=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
   public static extern void mouse_event(long dwFlags, long dx, long dy, long cButtons, long dwExtraInfo);

   private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
   private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
   private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
   private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;


   public void DoMouseClick()
   {
      //Call the imported function with the cursor's current position
      int X = Cursor.Position.X;
      int Y = Cursor.Position.Y;
      mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to make a **virtual mouse device** to work correctly

It will be difficult to make maybe try to use external DLLs

Comment: do you know any source or any other things ?